# SAS macros multiple statements

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I start with some example. I have "schools" variable like "harvard and oxford", "only harvard" etc. I want to find in "schools" variable only these cases which contain only one school name ("place" variable). I have "place" variable in dataset bbb which I put in listplace ("harvard!oxford!wse), "opinion" variable which I put in listopinion ("8!8!9) and "country" variable which I put in listcountry ("usa!uk!france"). I want to make macro which find in "schools" variable only these cases which contains two school names (zm1). Then, I want to add to them appropriate item from listopinion and listplace.
"Place" is school name, "opinion" is average rate and "country" is origin of this rate.

That's my first dataset:
 place  opinion     country
 - "harvard"    8       "usa"
 - "oxford"     8       "uk"
 - "wse"            9       "france"

That's my second dataset:

schools
 - harvard best
 - only harvard should be chosen
 - we dont't have any values
 - cake

That's what I want to have as results of my code (only two observation, not four as it is in "schools" variable):

schools                          opinion   country
 - "harvard very special"           8       "usa"
 - "only harvard should be chosen"  8       "usa"

How can I make three %do until loops with %let statements?

```
    data aaa;
    input  schools;
    datalines;
    "harvard and oxford"
    "only harvard should be chosen"
    "cheese, cake, pizza"
    "we dont't have any values"
    ;
    run;
    data bbb;
    input  place opinion country;
    datalines;
    "harvard" 8 "usa"
    "oxford" 8 "uk"
    "wse" 9 "france"
    ;
    run;
    data ccc;
    set
    proc sql noprint;
    select opinion
    into :listopinion separated by "!"
    from aaa
    ;
    run;
    quit;
    proc sql noprint;
    select country
    into :listcountry separated by "!"
    from aaa
    ;
    run;
    quit;
    proc sql noprint;
    select place
    into :listplace separated by "!"
    from aaa
    ;
    run;
    quit;
    %let i_1 =1;
    %let i_2 =1;
    %let i_2 =1;
    %do %until (%qscan(&listplace,&i_1,'!') = %str());
             %do %until (%qscan(&listopinion,&i_2,'!') = %str());
                      %do %until (%qscan(&listcountry,&i_3,'!') = %str());                
                          %let zm1=%scan(&listplace,&i_1,'!');
                               find(school,"&zm1")=1 or
                          %let zm2=%scan(&listopinion,&i_2,'!')
                          %let zm3=%scan(&lista3,&i_3,'!');
                          %let i_3=%eval(&i_3+1);
                      %end;
                 %let i_2=%eval(&i_2+1);
             %end;
        %let i_1=%eval(&i_1+1);
    %end;
    run;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for posting the code that you have. Please edit your question to show code that we can just copy and paste to replicate the issue and please specify what the issue is, e.g., copy an error message from the log, or do you get a different value from what you expected, in which case say what you expected and what you actually got. It should all help.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help make improvements to your question.

Comment: No need to increment your loop counters by hand. `%do &i_sel1 = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&lista1,!));`.  Do not add quotes where they are not needed. Did you intend to treat either  `'` or `|` as delimiters when scanning the list macro variables?  Or did you just intend to use `|` as the only delimiter?

Comment: Do you want to find schools that have an item from both list1 and list2?   Or do you just want to find schools that are in either list1 or in list2?  If the later then don't nest the %DO loops.  If the former then are the lists matched by position? So the first item in list1 is linked to the first item in list2.  Or do you want to pair the first item in list1 with every item in list2?

Comment: So you want to match on ITEM1 and then create new variables (or overwrite existing variables) using the values of ITEM2 and ITEM3? So you want to generate more than just part of a statement. You want to generate multiple statements.  Please edit your question to clearly show what the actual SAS code (no macro variables or macro logic) that you need to create for one set of (ITEM1,ITEM2,ITEM3) values.  So if ITEM1 is HARVARD then your find function call would look like `find(school,"HARVARD")`.

Comment: Maybe more code would be helpful. It looks this is one example on where it is not useful to use macros.

Comment: Please show the **SAS code** you want to create and we can show you how to write **MACRO logic** to create it.  Until you know what SAS code you want attempting to write macro logic to generate it is going to be unproductive. Look at the form of my answer.

Comment: Show what you want as the result of combining AAA with BBB.

Comment: I added everything to my post- sorry if it hasn't good format but I can't paste images ;/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like for your test of school you want to test if two or more of the names in the list exist in the value of school.

So if your list of schools to find looks like:

```
%let list=harvard|oxford|wse;
```

then you want to generate something like:

```
if sum( 0<findw(school,"harvard",,'i')
      , 0<findw(school,"oxford",,'i')
      , 0<findw(school,"wse",,'i')
      ) >= 2 then do;
...
end;
```

So you might use something like this:

```
if sum(

%let sep=;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list,|));
  &sep  0<findw(school,"%qscan(&list,&i,|)",,'i')
  %let sep=,;
%end;

) >= 2 then do;
...
end;
```

I have no idea what you want to do with the other two lists.  I think you want to use them to generate some SAS code where I have left `...`.

Comment: yes this is partially what I want. And for the results of this code I have to add "opinion" and "country" variables. I don't know whether it's a good idea to put them into lists (when I did this I had in all cases "opinion"=1 and "country"=1). Should I treat them or not as macro variables?

Comment: In what way does the lists of opinion and country related to the list of schools?  Perhaps the list of schools is really a list of lists? You can do that using two different delimiters.  For example you make a list of colleges that includes BIGTEN and SEC schools in separate lists by using `,` as one delimiter and `|` as the other:  `list1=MSU,OSU,PENNST|LSU,FLORIDA,GEORGIA`

Comment: "Schools" variable is only a list of very different examples (sometimes ever like "cheese, cake, pizza" what is wrong and that's I have to use "place" variable to add special conditions) which can be or not related. "Place", "opinion" and "country" are from the same dataset, "schools" is from the other.

Comment: Does that mean you want to include them in the generated series of tests but testing a different dataset variable? Should be easy. Again, **first** write out the actual SAS code you want to generate and **then** think about how to generate it with macro logic.

Comment: Are you saying the test is combination of (2 or more schools in the list1) AND (country is in the list2) AND (place is in list3)?  If so what do you want to DO when that condition is met?

Comment: Don't write macro code until you can write SAS code.  Show the data you have and what you want as output.  So far you have just showed the data about the tests (macro variables), but you have not showed the data you are actually trying to manipulate. Show what you want as the result of combining AAA with BBB